# Knockout validation - isValid() always true after value change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have the following scenario:

```
function ViewModel(){

    var self = this;

    self.newQty = ko.observable().extend({        
        pattern: {
            message: "Wrong!",
            params: new RegExp("^[1-9][0-9]*(\\,\\d{1,2})?|0+\\,\\d{1,2}$")
        }
    });

    self.newQty.subscribe(function() {
        if(self.newQty.isValid())
            doStuff();
    })
}
```

`newQty` field is bound to an `input` element.

If I type "123" into the `input` box, `isValid()` evaluates to `true`, and if I type "asd" into the `input` box the `isValid()` evaluates to `false`.

The problem manifests itself when I change "123" to "123a". `isValid()` still evaluates to true.

My question is: is there a way to manualy force re-evaluation of the field `newQty`? I found some posts that sugest calling `valueHasMutated()` but I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error when I use it.

I use Knockout 2.3.0 and latest version of Knockout-validation plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not escaping your alternation (`|`).  If you add parenthesis it should work:

```
params: new RegExp("^([1-9][0-9]*(\\,\\d{1,2})?|0+\\,\\d{1,2})$")
```

You can test it in the browser console:

```
'1234a'.test(/^[1-9][0-9]*(\\,\\d{1,2})?|0+\\,\\d{1,2}$/) //returns true
'1234a'.test(/^([1-9][0-9]*(\\,\\d{1,2})?|0+\\,\\d{1,2})$/) //returns false
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent a lot of time looking in the wrong direction. What can I say, Regex is like magic to me :)

Comment: No problem -- Regexpal.com is a good place to test these sorts of things also.  (I have no affiliation with the site, just have used it a lot over the years).